# Java: Iterating HashMap - Algorithm needed

Tags: java, algorithm, list, iterator

I have a list of names, say 8 names: Joe, Bob, Andrew, Bill, Charlie, Sarah, Ann, Victor

The count of names might differ**.

1) What should I use as name list? Hashmap, Vector, Hashtable, List, ArrayList?

2) I need to match them up like this: Joe-Bob, Andrew-Bill, Charlie-Sarah, Ann-Victor. Could you please show me an example how to make a loop which would do so?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain the logic of the algorithm in plain english? How are names mapped together? Where is the Vector?

Comment: Hey, I've modified the post. Sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashmaps have no order. If you want to insert a list of names like you want, you'd do something like the following (with an array):

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length - 1; i += 2) {
    hashMap.add(myArray[i], myArray[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have this question: Will it work if I want to remove two persons from the list when I match them up? Won't java complain that arraylist was modified?

Comment: You can modify the array just fine in a `for` loop - it's only a `foreach` loop that causes problems. Of course, one thing to keep in mind is that you'll need to adjust the value of your index accordingly.

Comment: Shall I do i = i-2 then (when I matched up two people, added them to hashmap, I want to remove them from myArray, after that I do i = i-2)? Is that efficient algorithm?

Comment: An array and an ArrayList are different things. Removing things from an ArrayList that you're looping over (if, say, the loop above were using an ArrayList instead of an array) would be a bad idea.

Comment: @Andrey: What do you mean by "remove them from myArray" though? You can set the entires at those indices to null, but you can't "remove them (changing the size of the array) as you can with a List.

Comment: You can remove them, but you just need to keep in mind that the size of the list changes, and all the existing elements will "shift" to take up the spaces of the removed elements. The question is: do you really need to remove them in the loop? You could process the entire list and then (outside the loop) do `list.clear()`.

Comment: when I said myArray, I ment ArrayList, sorry.
Well, the problem is that simultaneous threads will are elements to this arrayList outside the loop, so I can not clear the entire ArrayList just when I am finished the loop, because there are going to be more unpaired people by that time.

Comment: Concurrency is a whole other issue. Removing elements in one thread while another thread is adding will be really bad. Consider using something like an `ArrayBlockingQueue` from the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Comment: Using an `Map` might not be appropriate at all if the initial list contains duplicate elements.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) What should I use as name list? Hashmap, Vector, Hashtable, List, ArrayList?

Well, it depends on your needs :) But, because of the question and because you are mixing collection interfaces (e.g. `List`) and concrete implementations (e.g. `ArrayList` or `Vector`), I think that you should start with the basics. An **awesome** resource for this is the [**Trail: Collections**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) from The Java(tm) Tutorials, a really highly recommended reading.

First, you need to understand the various collection interfaces and their purpose. Then you'll choose a concrete implementations. The [Interfaces](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html) section of the tutorial that I'm quoting below will help you for the first step:

> The following list describes the core
>   collection interfaces:
>
> - `Collection` — the root of the collection hierarchy. A collection
>     represents a group of objects known as
>     its elements. The `Collection` interface
>     is the least common denominator that
>     all collections implement and is used
>     to pass collections around and to
>     manipulate them when maximum
>     generality is desired. Some types of
>     collections allow duplicate elements,
>     and others do not. Some are ordered
>     and others are unordered. The Java
>     platform doesn't provide any direct
>     implementations of this interface but
>     provides implementations of more
>     specific subinterfaces, such as `Set`
>     and `List`. Also see [The Collection
>     Interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) section.
> - `Set` — a collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. This
>     interface models the mathematical set
>     abstraction and is used to represent
>     sets, such as the cards comprising a
>     poker hand, the courses making up a
>     student's schedule, or the processes
>     running on a machine. See also [The Set
>     Interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) section.
> - `List` — an ordered collection (sometimes called a sequence). Lists
>     can contain duplicate elements. The
>     user of a List generally has precise
>     control over where in the list each
>     element is inserted and can access
>     elements by their integer index
>     (position). If you've used `Vector`,
>     you're familiar with the general
>     flavor of `List`. Also see [The List
>     Interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) section.
> - `Queue` — a collection used to hold multiple elements prior to processing.
>     Besides basic Collection operations, a
>     Queue provides additional insertion,
>     extraction, and inspection operations.
>
>   Queues typically, but do not
>     necessarily, order elements in a FIFO
>     (first-in, first-out) manner. Among
>     the exceptions are priority queues,
>     which order elements according to a
>     supplied comparator or the elements'
>     natural ordering. Whatever the
>     ordering used, the head of the queue
>     is the element that would be removed
>     by a call to `remove` or `poll`. In a FIFO
>     queue, all new elements are inserted
>     at the tail of the queue. Other kinds
>     of queues may use different placement
>     rules. Every `Queue` implementation must
>     specify its ordering properties. Also
>     see [The Queue Interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html) section.
> - `Map` — an object that maps keys to values. A Map cannot contain duplicate
>     keys; each key can map to at most one
>     value. If you've used `Hashtable`,
>     you're already familiar with the
>     basics of `Map`. Also see [The Map
>     Interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) section.

In your case, I don't think that you want a `Queue`, I'm not sure you need a `Map`, I think you want to allow duplicate elements so you don't want a `Set` and this leaves us with a `List`.

Regarding the concrete implementation, if a thread safe implementation is not needed, [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) - or [`LinkedList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), depending on the algorithm in 2) - might be a good choice). But really, have a look at the [Implementations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html) section of the tutorial to learn more.

> 2) I need to match them up like this: Joe-Bob, Andrew-Bill, Charlie-Sarah, Ann-Victor. Could you please show me an example how to make a loop which would do so?

If the initial list can contain duplicate elements, I wouldn't use a `Map` to store matched names (because a `Map` cannot contain duplicate keys). So, I'd create a `Couple` class to store associated names:

```
public class Couple {
    private name1;
    private name2;
    ...
}
```

and use a `List<Couple>` to store matched names. But, because the logic of the algorithm is still not clear (does the initial list always contain an odd number of elements? is one element always associated with the immediate next one?), I can't provide more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you mean by "associating" the names and what you need to do with them. Also you don't say whether the names are unique.

You can pair names this way:

```
String input = "Joe, Bob, Andrew, Bill, Charlie, Sarah, Ann, Victor";
String names[] = input.split(",");
Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i=0; i<names.length; i+=2) {
  output.put(names[i].trim(), names[i+1].trim());
}
```

and then do:

```
output.remove("Joe"); // Joe is paired with Bob
```

If you also need to associate Bob with Joe, you could do it this way:

```
String input = "Joe, Bob, Andrew, Bill, Charlie, Sarah, Ann, Victor";
String names[] = input.split(",");
Map<String, String> output = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (int i=0; i<names.length; i+=2) {
  String first = names[i].trim();
  String second = names[i+1].trim();
  output.put(first, second);
  output.put(second, first);
}
```

and then do:

```
String other = output.remove("Joe");
output.remove(other);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your choice should depend on the purpose for which you want these names. Do you want efficient search over the list for a given last name? If yes, then you should follow Anon's proposal.

Otherwise, you could just create a class where you could keep information about each person (first name, last name, telephone, etc.) and use a Vector to keep the instances of this class. An example of this class could be:

```
class PersonDetails {

    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public PersonDetails(String fn, String ln) {
        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
    }
}
```

For the insertion of the names in the vector you could use something like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i += 2) {
    vector.add(new PersonDetails(nameArray[i], nameArray[i+1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array to start with but want to remove elements as you process them, first convert it to a `List` of some kind. Also, removing items from the beginning of an `ArrayList` can be very expensive, so if you have a lot of names, you may want to use either a `LinkedList` (though there are very few reasons to actually use this between performance and memory utilization, it is better to have a circular `List` but this does not come standard with Java).

So, in your case, you know you will be processing the list sequentially so the most efficient I can think of is to create an `ArrayList` and reverse it then remove from the end, like this:

```
private Map matchNames(String[] names) {
    List namesList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(names));
    Collections.reverse(namesList);

    Map result = new HashMap(namesList.size() / 2);
    while (!namesList.isEmpty()) {
        result.put(namesList.remove(namesList.size() - 1), 
            namesList.remove(namesList.size() - 1));
    }

    return result;
}
```